# Does anyone have an extra PR2 replacement power board? (PR2 replacement parts)

Tags: pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear PR2 users,

I am maintaining a PR2 at the Institute for Artificial Intelligence of the University of Bremen.

We have been diagnosing an issue with our robot since September 15th together with the help of Clearpath Robotics, but sadly they don't have any new Power-Boards on stock, and they are working under pressure to repair another board to send to us. Since we depend on the PR2 for the work of a lot of researchers, this has been affecting us heavily.

The issue started with under-voltage warnings on the right arm, which were halting the robot, happening once or twice a day, and it got worse until the robot can not even complete self-calibration without halting. We now disconnected the right arm, but we need both for some experiments.

It is a long shot, but who knows?:  Does any other PR2 team have a working power board that they are not using currently?

Did anyone else have problems with the power board or other components of the PR2 that needed replacement? We had very few issues with our PR2 in TUM (Munich), but the one here has had many more. I'm interested in your experiences with the hardware.

Is there a mailing list of PR2 users/owners?  I would gladly move this question there if answers.ros.org is not an appropriate place.

Thanks in advance!

Alexis

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195763/does-anyone-have-an-extra-pr2-replacement-power-board?-(pr2-replacement-parts)/) by [AlexisMaldonado](https://answers.ros.org/users/1464/alexismaldonado/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-10-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Alexis,

For the mailing lists, you can request access to the PR2 Google Groups which is a replacement for the old lists.willowgarage.com pr2-users mailing list. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pr2_users

---

Originally posted by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) with karma: 644 on 2014-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlexisMaldonado](https://answers.ros.org/users/1464/alexismaldonado/) on 2014-10-24**:
Thanks a lot for the link to the new mailing list. Will try there.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best place to reach PR2 users is the pr2-users mailing list or administrators on pr2-admin  The [PR2 support site](http://pr2s.clearpathrobotics.com/wiki/Documentation) links to lists.willowgarage.com as the home for those lists. But that site appears to be down. I suspect the mailing lists were migrated, but I don't know where to.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-10-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) on 2014-10-23**:
Hi Tully, we've moved to a google group now for the PR2 users since the WG virtual server that was hosting them was taken offline. They can now be found here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pr2_users

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-10-23**:
It would be great to update the links on the pr2s site homepage.

**Comment by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) on 2014-11-08**:
I agree, will do.